# Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ with $ x>y>z>1$ and $1/x+1/y+1/z >1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, integers

> Find all $x,y,z \in \mathbb Z$ with $ x>y>z>1$ and $1/x+1/y+1/z >1$.

I found only one example  $2,3,4 $
 Because,
$4>3>2>1$ and 
 $1/2+1/3+1/4=13/12>1$

I tried to add the L.H.S. of the inequality to get $\frac{xy+yz+xz}{xyz} >1$ 
 which gives, $ xy+yz+xz>xyz $
which provides no more information to proceed. Confused please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, there are only two of those triplets: $(2,3,4)$ and $(2,3,5)$. Here's the proof, why there are no more of those triplets.

Assume that $z\neq 2$ which means that $x>y>z\geq 3$ and therefore we have $\frac 1 x< \frac 1 y< \frac 1 z \leq \frac{1}{3}$ so if we sum these fractions up we get some value $<1$. This shows that $z = 2$.

Now assume that $y \neq 3$, so $x>y\geq 4$, analogously we have $\frac 1 x < \frac 1 y \leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac 1 z = \frac{1}{2}$. Adding up those fractions gives again a value $<1$. Therefore $y=3$.

Lastly we can just try $x=4$ and $x=5$ to see that this works. For $x=6$ we get $\frac 1 2 + \frac 1 3 + \frac 1 6 = 1 \not > 1$, so there are no more solutions.